# Uncaught ReferenceError: getAuth is not defined - Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, authentication, google-analytics

I leave the code of the index.html and the index.js to help me, analytics if it works but auth does not work because of the error that appears when doing a test, thanks

```
index.html
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-auth.js";

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "---",
      authDomain: "---",
      databaseURL: "---",
      projectId: "---",
      storageBucket: "---",
      messagingSenderId: "---",
      appId: "---",
      measurementId: "---"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>

index.js
getAuth(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('Usuario conectado');
  } else {
    console.log('Ningún usuario conectado');
  }
});
```

error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: getAuth is not defined
at index.js:1:1

I have tried to test the analytics function and it works but I do not understand why the authentication function does not work if I have used the same system

Comment: `getAuth` is scoped to your module in `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

getAuth is only visible insdite the `<script type="module">` tag, so using it in other javascript files will result in an undefined variable

You can define a global function and call it from the module tag to insert those variables as parameters, it is importan to define that global function before the script module tag

```js
// load this script before script type module tag
function moduleLoadedWithParams(getAuth) {
    console.log(getAuth);
  
  auth = 'example'; // will throw error, but getAuth function is called
  getAuth(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('Usuario conectado');
    } else {
      console.log('Ningún usuario conectado');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-auth.js";

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    
    window.moduleLoadedWithParams(getAuth);    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app); //Add this line
```